# unable to find valid certification path to requested target when using two service together

Tags: java, tomcat, https

I have web application in java, running in tomcat web server.
I call two https service. in my config file i can enable them
when I enable just one service, every thing is ok and i got response.
but when i enable both of them together, one of my services would get the following error:

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I would try some solutions:

- update jdk version
- add certificate manually with ketools
- consider my firewall

but none of this would help me
also, i test m code on other server, and it was correct.

Comment: That error has to do with a client not trusting the TLS certificate provided by a server. When does this error occur? Something is connecting to something else. What are those two somethings?

Comment: my program is calling two external https service. it can call them seperately. but when call both of them, it got the error

Comment: How are you connecting? (The answer should be something like "I use `HttpsURLConnection`",  or "I use `http-client`" or "I use [library X]".) How are you configuring that client's trust store(s) and key store(s)?